# XNA - Weird bug with 2D Sprite Rotation

Tags: xna, 2d, mathematics

I have a problem with my XNA Game, I have a function where I need my sprite to face towards an enemy, using this code:

```
        Vector2 currentPosition = Position;
        Vector2 nearestEnemy = gameObjectManager.GetNearestEnemy(Position, GameObjectTypes.Zombie);

        Orientation = (float)Math.Atan2(nearestEnemy.Y - currentPosition.Y, nearestEnemy.X - currentPosition.X)
```

As found on an XNA forum results in my character looking 90 degrees away from the enemy.

Adding "MathHelper.ToRadians(90);" to the end of my Orientation assignment fixes this bug, why is this happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that your sprite may be incorrectly oriented in the source file.  Atan2, I believe, returns the angle of the given vector, where zero indicates a vector pointing "to the right" (+X, Y=0).  If your sprite file does not point "to the right", you will have to make angle corrections.

Comment: Ah ok, I have pointed my sprite upwards! Haha! Many thanks!